# Variables en SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Tengo el siguiente problema,

He intentando cambiar la siguiente sentencia [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) en [access](/questions/tagged/access) para incluir variables, pero me da error.

Si no uso variables la query funciona sin problemas.

**Sentencia SQL**

```
parameters @start date;
parameters @finish date;
set @start = #4/1/2017 0:0:1#;
set @finish = #4/30/2017 23:59:0#;
SELECT dbo_t_Agent.PeripheralNumber, dbo_t_Agent.EnterpriseName,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.CallsHandledToHalf) AS SumaDeCallsHandledToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.AgentOutCallsToHalf) AS SumaDeAgentOutCallsToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.HandledCallsTimeToHalf) AS SumaDeHandledCallsTimeToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.AgentOutCallsTimeToHalf) AS SumaDeAgentOutCallsTimeToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.InternalCallsRcvdToHalf) AS SumaDeInternalCallsRcvdToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.TransferredInCallsToHalf) AS SumaDeTransferredInCallsToHalf
FROM dbo_t_Agent INNER JOIN dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour ON dbo_t_Agent.SkillTargetID = dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.SkillTargetID
WHERE (((dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.DateTime) Between @start And @finish))
GROUP BY dbo_t_Agent.PeripheralNumber, dbo_t_Agent.EnterpriseName
HAVING (((Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.CallsHandledToHalf))>0));
```

**¿Qué he intentado?**

He cambiado los sets, dado que están declarados como fecha, de quitar la **#**. Pero no está ahí el problema, porque me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

```
set @start = 4/1/2017 0:0:1;
set @finish = 4/30/2017 23:59:0;
```

**¿Qué error sale al ejecutar la query?**

> Instrucción SQL no válida, se esperaba 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT' o 'UPDATE'

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Es posible que realmente no se pueda usar variables en las sentencias de Access?

Comment: quiza deberias poner la consulta con los literales en el `sql` en vez de con variables ..  no se por que sucede

Comment: Sí, efectivamente con los literales funciona bien, pero quería probar a ponerlo con variables. Lo mismo terminaré haciendo alguna función para que lo lea de un formulario para no tener que estar editando constantemente. Gracias!

Comment: nada .. a ver si alguien sabe la respuesta. No tengo mucho tiempo para investigar yo mismo . Un saludo ^^

Comment: ¿Has verificado si estas usando el terminador de sentencias correcto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo escribiendo el nombre de la variable entre corchetes cuadrados, para que access te solicite los parametros.

```
SELECT dbo_t_Agent.PeripheralNumber, dbo_t_Agent.EnterpriseName,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.CallsHandledToHalf) AS SumaDeCallsHandledToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.AgentOutCallsToHalf) AS SumaDeAgentOutCallsToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.HandledCallsTimeToHalf) AS SumaDeHandledCallsTimeToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.AgentOutCallsTimeToHalf) AS SumaDeAgentOutCallsTimeToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.InternalCallsRcvdToHalf) AS SumaDeInternalCallsRcvdToHalf,
        Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.TransferredInCallsToHalf) AS SumaDeTransferredInCallsToHalf
FROM dbo_t_Agent INNER JOIN dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour ON dbo_t_Agent.SkillTargetID = dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.SkillTargetID
WHERE (((dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.DateTime) Between [fecha inicial] And [fecha final]))
GROUP BY dbo_t_Agent.PeripheralNumber, dbo_t_Agent.EnterpriseName
HAVING (((Sum(dbo_t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour.CallsHandledToHalf))>0));
```

Con esto solucionas el problema de la consulta y la solicitud de los parámetros de una vez.